# Prove: The set of all interior points of a set E is always open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

> **Prove:** The set of all interior points of a set E is always open.

Here is my proof; is it valid?

Let $P_a$ be an interior point of $E$. Then, $P_a$ has a neighborhood $$N_{r_{P_a}}\subset E$$

By theorems, every neighborhood is an open set and the union of any collection of opens sets is also open, so $$\bigcup_a N_{r_{P_a}}$$ is open, hence the set of all interior points of $E$ is open.

[pic of proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRqgx.png)

Comment: Looks good to me. One thing is that the index is not necessarily countable so you might write $\bigcup_{a\in A}$.

Comment: In some books, the interior of $E$ is _defined_ as the union of all open sets contained in $E$. It's an interpretation that's worth being aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I add this to give this old post an answer.

---

Your proof might be **incomplete** because you do not prove that the set $\bigcup_a{N_{r_{P_a}}}$, which you actually show to be open, is indeed your desired set of all interior points. E.g. how do you know that $N_{r_{P_a}}$ does only contain interior points of $E$?

However, this last question is not hard to answer. You just need to observe that since $N_{r_{P_a}}$ is open as well, every point $x\in N_{r_{P_a}}$ has a neighborhood $M\subseteq N_{r_{P_a}}\subseteq E$, hence $x$ is also interior to $E$.